# Convert token request from Sign in with Apple returns HTTP 400 form Django REST social auth

Tags: ios, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, sign-in-with-apple

I implemented Sign in with Apple backend to Django according to articles below

- https://medium.com/@kaseyb002/apple-sign-in-with-django-rest-framework-3fdbdae6a1d4
- https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/apple.html

When I send convert-token request from iOS App to Django it returns HTTP 400.

In the same project(iOS app and Django backend), I also implemented Facebook auth and this is working fine.

My guess is that request from iOS app is OK but some settings on Django is wrong but I am not sure about it.

What Im I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

---

### Django Code

#### Django settings.py, Sign in with Apple related code

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Apple (Sign in with Apple)
    'social_core.backends.apple.AppleIdAuth',
)


# Social Auth: Apple
SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_CLIENT = os.environ['MY_BUNDLE_ID']                   # App's Bundle ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_TEAM   = '<I set some value see comment on the right>'# From Apple Dev Portal  Membership Detail page
SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_KEY    = '<I set some value see comment on the right>'# Created it from Apple Dev Portal
SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_SECRET = os.environ['MY_SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_SECRET'] # I set some random string
SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_SCOPE  = ['email', 'name']                            # Same as ones set on iOS app
SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_EMAIL_AS_USERNAME = True
```

#### Django settings.py, other code may be related to the problem(Mainly Facebook Auth related)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication', 
        'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Facebook OAuth2
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    # Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

#### Django's Custom view returning token

```
from rest_framework_social_oauth2 import views
from oauth2_provider.models import AccessToken
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ConvertTokenWithUserView(views.ConvertTokenView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ConvertTokenWithUserView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

        print('')
        print('--- Response ---')
        print(response) # This outputs 400

        token = AccessToken.objects.get(token = response.data['access_token'])
        user = token.user
        return Response(
            {
                'access_token' : response.data['access_token'],
                'refresh_token': response.data['refresh_token'],
                'user_id'      : user.pk
            }
        )
```

---

### iOS Code

#### Part retrieving JWT from Sign in with Apple

```
extension LoginViewController {
    
    @objc func didTapAppleButton() {
        
        guard #available(iOS 13.0, *) else { return }
        
        let provider: ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider = .init()
        let request = provider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        
        let authController: ASAuthorizationController = .init(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authController.delegate = self
        authController.presentationContextProvider = self
        
        authController.performRequests()
    }
}


@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension LoginViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    
    public func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        
        guard
            let credential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential,
            let jwt        = credential.identityToken,
            let jwtToken   = String(data: jwt, encoding: .utf8)
        else  { return }
        
        // Send jwtToken to server
        eventHandling?.didReceive(signInWithAppleAccessToken: jwtToken)
        
    }
    
    public func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {}
}
```

#### Param sent to Django

```
public struct AccessTokenRequestParam: Codable {
    
    public let grantType: String = "convert_token"
    
    /// Value from Djagno poject
    public let clientId: String = UseCaseSettings.shared.djangoAuthClientId
    
    /// Value from Djagno poject
    public let clientSecret: String = UseCaseSettings.shared.djangoAuthClientSecret
    
    /// either "facebook" or "apple-id"
    public let backend: String
    
    /// either token from Facbook or Apple
    public let token: String
    
    
    
    public init(token: String, socialTokenProvider: SocialTokenProvider) {
        self.token = token
        self.backend = socialTokenProvider.backendIdentifier
    }
}


public extension AccessTokenRequestParam {
    
    enum SocialTokenProvider {
        case facebook
        case apple
        
        var backendIdentifier: String {
            switch self {
            case .facebook: return "facebook"
            case .apple   : return "apple-id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Is it working now? Cause I need to copy your code if it is.

Comment: I got it working, I used other suggestions which I googled

Comment: Can you give me a link?

Comment: @VoidMain https://medium.com/@aamishbaloch/sign-in-with-apple-in-your-django-python-backend-b501daa835a9 Here it is

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "social_core.backends.apple.AppleIdAuth" in Authentication backends, so should be like this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Facebook OAuth2
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    ### Added ### - Apple backend
    'social_core.backends.apple.AppleIdAuth', 

    # Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```